# Differential equation for a vector potential

Tags: vector-fields, potential-theory, electromagnetism

From Helmholtz’s theorem, any smooth vector field $\mathbf{F}$ that goes to zero at infinite distance can be uniquely decomposed everywhere in the sum of a divergence free component and an irrotational component.

In particular if it's conservative, one can prove that it can be uniquely determined everywhere solving the Poisson equation for its potential:
\begin{equation}
\Delta\varphi(\mathbf{r})=f(\mathbf{r})
\end{equation}
where $f$ is the divergence of $\mathbf{F}$. This equation can be found from the definition of scalar potential provided by Helmholtz’s theorem
\begin{equation}
\varphi(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\frac{f(\mathbf{r}')}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|}d\mathbf{r}'
\end{equation}
I was wondering if something similar can be done (and how) for the vector potential, i.e., if it's possible to uniquely determine a solenoidal vector field by solving a differential equation that involves its vector potential and its curl starting from the Helmholtz’s theorem
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r}):=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\frac{\mathbf{C}(\mathbf{r}')}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|}d\mathbf{r}'
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{C}$ is the curl of $\mathbf{F}$. So I'm assuming this field goes to zero at infinite distance and it's smooth. In case this is not possible, I would appreciate a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: If you additionally assume  that 

$$ F= \nabla\times G  , \quad \nabla\cdot G = 0$$

then when you take the curl again and use the double curl identity $\nabla \times (\nabla\times G) =   \nabla(\nabla\cdot G)-\Delta G$ you get
$$ -\Delta G = \nabla\times F  $$
which is again a Poisson equation so you can solve for $G$. this is called the Biot-Savart law. Without this assumption you still have an equation but its more complicated

Comment: @CalvinKhor That's the Coulomb gauge. I was hoping for a more general approach.

Comment: well I have no idea what a Coulomb gauge is but it wasn’t in your question despite being a partial answer hence my comment. That’s the end of what I know so gl

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question and it is addressed in some treatments of classical field theory. Specifically, I think the answer you seek is nicely discussed in the excellent discussion in pages 52-54 in Morse and Feshbach's book, "Methods of Theoretical Physics".

It can be found online here, for example:
https://archive.org/details/morse_feshbach1/morse_feshbach1